# Read from CSV file in C returns same value everytime

Tags: c, csv

I have a csv file having values

```
1,A,X
2,B,Y
3,C,Z
```

I have to read the CSV file line by line and keep it in a Structure array.
The values are going fine each time in the for loop. But at the end when I am printing the Array, only the last value is being printed.
Somebody please tell me where am I doing the logical error?

```
struct proc
{
    char *x;
    char *y;
};

void main()
{
    fflush(stdin);
    fflush(stdout);

    const char s[2] = ",";
    char *token;
    int rows=0,i,tokenVal=0,rowCount=0;
    FILE *fpCount = fopen("data.csv","r");
    if(fpCount != NULL)
    {
        char lineCount[20];
        while(fgets(lineCount, sizeof lineCount, fpCount))
            rows++;
    }
    struct proc *pi[rows];
    for(i=0;i<rows;i++)
        pi[i] = (struct proc*) malloc(sizeof(struct proc));
    FILE *fp = fopen("data.csv", "r");
    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        char line[20];        
        while(fgets(line, sizeof line, fp) != NULL)
        {
            printf("Start rowCount = %d\t",rowCount);
            token = strtok(line, s);
            while(token!=NULL)
            {
                if(tokenVal==0)
                    {
                        pi[rowCount]->Id =token;
                    }
                if(tokenVal==1)
                {
                    pi[rowCount]->act = token;
                }
                printf("\n");
                tokenVal++;
                token = strtok(NULL,s);
            }

            tokenVal = 0;
            printf("end rowCount = %d\t",rowCount);
            rowCount++;
        }
        fclose(fp);
    } else {
        perror("data.csv");
    }
    printf("total %d",rowCount);
    int k=0;
    for(k=0;k<rowCount;k++)
    {
        printf(" %d = %s----%s",k,pi[k]->Id,pi[k]->act);
    }
}
```

Comment: You read each line into `line`; you copy pointers into your array, all pointing at `line`.  At the end of the input, `line` contains the remnants of the last line left by `strtok()` — so all the entries in the array are pointing at the last line.  You need to duplicate (`strdup()` or equivalent) the values (tokens) to be saved into the array.

Comment: Note the details of [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin); it is not portable.

Comment: This is Magic!!! Thank you so much. The Code is working fine now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Diagnosis

The fundamental problem you face is that you are saving pointers to the variable `line` in your structures, but each new line overwrites what was previously in `line`, so at the end, only data from the last line is present.  It is fortuitous that your lines of data are all the same 'shape'; if the fields were of different lengths, you'd have more interesting, but equally erroneous, results.

Consequently, you need to save a copy of each field, not simply a pointer to the field.  The simple way to do that is with POSIX function [`strdup()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html).  If you don't have the function, you can create it:

```
char *strdup(const char *str)
{
    size_t len = strlen(str) + 1;
    char *rv = malloc(len);
    if (rv != 0)
        memmove(rv, str, len);  // or memcpy
    return rv;
}
```

Your code doesn't compile; your data structure has elements `x` and `y` but your code uses elements `Id` and `act`.  You use a VLA of pointers to your `struct proc`, but it would be sensible to allocate an array of the structure, either as a VLA or via `malloc()` et al.  You should check memory allocations — there isn't a way to check VLAs, though (one reason to use dynamic allocation instead).  You could rewind the file instead of reopening it.  (It's a good idea to use a variable to hold the file name, even if you only open it once; it makes error reporting better.  Also, errors should stop the program, in general, though you did use `perror()` if the reopen operation failed — but not if the open failed.)  You don't need two arrays into which to read the lines.  It's a good idea to use far longer buffers for input lines.  You should free dynamically allocated memory.  Also, see [What should `main()` return in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/); the answer is `int` and not `void` (unless perhaps you are on Windows).

Here are three variants of your code, with various aspects of the issues outlined above more or less fixed.

#### VLA of pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct proc
{
    char *x;
    char *y;
};

int main(void)
{
    const char datafile[] = "data.csv";
    const char csv_delim[] = ",\n";
    int rows = 0, rowCount = 0;
    FILE *fpCount = fopen(datafile, "r");

    if (fpCount == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open '%s' for reading\n", datafile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char lineCount[2000];
    while (fgets(lineCount, sizeof(lineCount), fpCount))
        rows++;
    fclose(fpCount);

    printf("Read %d rows from '%s'\n", rows, datafile);

    struct proc *pi[rows];
    for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        pi[i] = (struct proc *)malloc(sizeof(struct proc));

    FILE *fp = fopen(datafile, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to reopen '%s' for reading\n", datafile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[2000];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Start rowCount = %d\t", rowCount);
        int tokenVal = 0;
        char *token = strtok(line, csv_delim);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (tokenVal == 0)
            {
                pi[rowCount]->x = strdup(token);
            }
            else if (tokenVal == 1)
            {
                pi[rowCount]->y = strdup(token);
            }
            printf("[%s]", token);
            tokenVal++;
            token = strtok(NULL, csv_delim);
        }
        printf("\tend rowCount = %d\n", rowCount);
        rowCount++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    /* Data validation */
    printf("total %d\n", rowCount);
    for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++)
    {
        printf("%d = [%s]----[%s]\n", k, pi[k]->x, pi[k]->y);
    }

    /* Release allocated memory */
    for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++)
    {
        free(pi[k]->x);
        free(pi[k]->y);
        free(pi[k]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### VLA of structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct proc
{
    char *x;
    char *y;
};

int main(void)
{
    const char datafile[] = "data.csv";
    const char csv_delim[] = ",\n";
    int rows = 0, rowCount = 0;
    FILE *fpCount = fopen(datafile, "r");

    if (fpCount == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open '%s' for reading\n", datafile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char lineCount[2000];
    while (fgets(lineCount, sizeof(lineCount), fpCount))
        rows++;
    fclose(fpCount);

    printf("Read %d rows from '%s'\n", rows, datafile);

    struct proc pi[rows];

    FILE *fp = fopen(datafile, "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to reopen '%s' for reading\n", datafile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[2000];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Start rowCount = %d\t", rowCount);
        int tokenVal = 0;
        char *token = strtok(line, csv_delim);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (tokenVal == 0)
            {
                pi[rowCount].x = strdup(token);
            }
            else if (tokenVal == 1)
            {
                pi[rowCount].y = strdup(token);
            }
            printf("[%s]", token);
            tokenVal++;
            token = strtok(NULL, csv_delim);
        }
        printf("\tend rowCount = %d\n", rowCount);
        rowCount++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    /* Data validation */
    printf("total %d\n", rowCount);
    for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++)
    {
        printf("%d = [%s]----[%s]\n", k, pi[k].x, pi[k].y);
    }

    /* Release allocated memory */
    for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++)
    {
        free(pi[k].x);
        free(pi[k].y);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

#### Dynamic array of structures

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct proc
{
    char *x;
    char *y;
};

int main(void)
{
    const char datafile[] = "data.csv";
    const char csv_delim[] = ",\n";
    int num_rows = 0, rowCount = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen(datafile, "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open '%s' for reading\n", datafile);
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char line[2000];
    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp))
        num_rows++;
    rewind(fp);

    printf("Read %d rows from '%s'\n", num_rows, datafile);

    struct proc *pi = calloc(num_rows, sizeof(*pi));
    if (pi == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate %zu bytes of memory\n", num_rows * sizeof(*pi));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), fp) != NULL)
    {
        printf("Start rowCount = %d\t", rowCount);
        int tokenVal = 0;
        char *token = strtok(line, csv_delim);
        while (token != NULL)
        {
            if (tokenVal == 0)
            {
                pi[rowCount].x = strdup(token);
                // null check
            }
            else if (tokenVal == 1)
            {
                pi[rowCount].y = strdup(token);
                // null check
            }
            printf("[%s]", token);
            tokenVal++;
            token = strtok(NULL, csv_delim);
        }
        printf("\tend rowCount = %d\n", rowCount);
        rowCount++;
    }

    fclose(fp);

    /* Data validation */
    printf("total %d\n", rowCount);
    for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++)
    {
        printf("%d = [%s]----[%s]\n", k, pi[k].x, pi[k].y);
    }

    /* Release allocated memory */
    for (int k = 0; k < rowCount; k++)
    {
        free(pi[k].x);
        free(pi[k].y);
    }
    free(pi);

    return 0;
}
```

Given a data file:

```
1,A,X
2,B,Y
3,C,Z
3192-2146-9913,Abelone,Zoophyte
```

all three programs produce the same output:

```
Read 4 rows from 'data.csv'
Start rowCount = 0  [1][A][X]   end rowCount = 0
Start rowCount = 1  [2][B][Y]   end rowCount = 1
Start rowCount = 2  [3][C][Z]   end rowCount = 2
Start rowCount = 3  [3192-2146-9913][Abelone][Zoophyte] end rowCount = 3
total 4
0 = [1]----[A]
1 = [2]----[B]
2 = [3]----[C]
3 = [3192-2146-9913]----[Abelone]
```

Answer (score 0):

In the **printf(" %d = %s----%s----%s",k,pi[k]->Id,pi[k]->act);**
There are four data 
%d
%s
%s
%s

but you set only three
k
pi[k]->Id
pi[k]->act